# How to identify all cells containing work starting with capital letter?

Tags: google-sheets

On google spreadsheet, how to identify all cells containing a word whom first cell is capitalized ?

Comment: What'll you do in js to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Terrible Q (no research shown, unclear, inconsistent, poor capitalisation, no sample data, bad grammar) but, perhaps, a very easy solution. Select all cells and apply a CF formula rule of:

```
 =regexmatch(A1,"\b[A-Z]")
```